# 19.10: gnome-shell crashes when using touch screen

Tags: gnome, dell, touchscreen

My question is about gnome-shell and touchscreens.

I have a dell xps 13 with an up to date ubuntu 19.10.

when using touch screen gestures in whatever application, game, brows
er.., after about 2 or 3 minutes, the gnome-shell crashes.

The problem occurred first after an update end of november I think.

Best /PS

syslog says:

```
   Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: Object Meta.BackgroundActor (0x55db68663270), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: JS ERROR: Error: Argument 'instance' (type interface) may not be null#012_init/GObject.Object.prototype.disconnect@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/GObject.js:508:16#012_onDestroy@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:210:13#012DesktopGrid</<@/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:115:45

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: == Stack trace for context 0x55db67641390 ==

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: #0   7fff8f0c2090 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/GObject.js:508 (7f297fcad8b0 @ 25)

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: #1   55db6bc1c968 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:210 (7f297d9d1dc0 @ 75)

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: #2   55db6bc1c8f0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desktop-icons@csoriano/desktopGrid.js:115 (7f297d9d19d0 @ 12)

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: clutter_actor_iter_next: assertion 'ri->age == ri->root->priv->age' failed

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 11

Jan 13 16:28:02 q gnome-shell[7160]: == Stack trace for context 0x55db67641390 ==

Jan 13 16:28:02 q ibus-daemon[7215]: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Service has no hold-off time (RestartSec=0), scheduling restart.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: gnome-shell-x11.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopped target GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopping GNOME X11 Session (session: ubuntu).

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopped target GNOME X11 Session.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopping GNOME X11 Session.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopped target GNOME Shell on X11.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopping GNOME Shell on X11.

Jan 13 16:28:02 q systemd[2088]: Stopped GNOME Shell on X11.
```

Comment: not a solution, but I used to get something like that problem. for that and other reasons I disabled the touchscreen with "xinput disable <device id> id got from "xin put"

Comment: I am having the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Had it on 19.10 as well. This was not an issue in 16.04

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know the details since I have no knowledge of or experience with Xorg code, I have what appears to be precisely the same problem on an HP Elitebook x360 1030 G2. I have only found discussion of this crash in a few places: your question right here, [this GTK bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1389), where a Gnome developer insists it is someone else's problem, and [this Xorg bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/625). It seems that there has been a fix merged into the X server for a year now, but this has only recently been backported (according to discussion on the Xorg bug). This makes my system more or less unusable with Gnome, and so I too am hopeful that the fix will eventually make it into Ubuntu. It appears that Ubuntu 20.04 will include a version of the package xserver-xorg-core with the fix, and so it is possible that updating to the daily releases will help for the moment. However, these daily releases are (in theory) less stable than standard releases, so please do back up all your files before going that route. Unfortunately, other than the daily release, your only good option is to wait for it to be fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can now confirm that this crash is still present on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Yoga.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not convinced either of those bugs are related to the bug in the OP - neither of them mention the failed assert in `clutter_actor_iter_next` described in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This crash is down to a bug in Mutter, the window manager underlying GNOME shell, as a GNOME shell maintainer [explained to me](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3055). The exact messages in the syslog can vary slightly depending on what GNOME extensions you have enabled, so if you have slightly different logs but identical symptoms, it's likely to be the same issue.

The ultimate root bug in mutter can be tracked [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1870867), and there is now a fix for it which I have been testing for a day and seems to work. By the time anyone reads this the patch will likely have been deployed anyway, but I'll explain how to install it anyway.

You can check your versions of the `mutter` and `libmutter` packages by running `dpkg -l | grep mutter`. You should see something like this:

```
ii  gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64                      3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        GObject introspection data for Mutter
ii  libmutter-6-0:amd64                        3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        window manager library from the Mutter window manager
ii  mutter                                     3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               amd64        Example window manager using GNOME's window manager library
ii  mutter-common                              3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2               all          shared files for the Mutter window manager
```

At minimum `libmutter` should be at `3.36.4` for you to have the fix. If you're reading this in the future and have similar symptoms but your `libmutter` is at a higher version, then this answer is not relevant to you. Otherwise, open the software update manager (`software-properties-gtk`, also known as "Software & Updates") and activate pre-release updates as in this screenshot:

[image]

You can now upgrade `libmutter` with the command `sudo apt install libmutter-6-0/focal-proposed`, *if you're using Ubuntu 20.04*, "Focal Fossa". For other versions of Ubuntu, substitute `focal` for the corresponding adjective, e.g. `bionic` for "Bionic Beaver". You may also want to upgrade `mutter` if it's a lower version than shown above, I'm not sure.

Reboot after installing the update, and if you like you can disable pre-release updates in the Software & Updates program afterwards.